# bash script command line passing double quotas does not work

Tags: bash

this is my bash script, test.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

printf '1st printf:\n%s\n\n\n' 'find . -name "*.[ch]"'${1}

printf '2nd printf:\n%s\n' 'find . -name "*.[ch]"'" ${1}"

find . -name "*.[ch]"  ${1}
```

I run it as `test.sh "-not -path \"*examples*\""` and here is the output:

```sh
1st printf:
find . -name "*.[ch]"-not


1st printf:
-path


1st printf:
"*examples*"


2nd printf:
find . -name "*.[ch]" -not -path "*examples*"
```

what I try to is to run `find . -name "*.[ch]" -not -path "*examples*"` inside the script. But the `$1` is treated like a list or something? How do I construct the right command line inside the script?

Comment: Learn to use arrays and know the concept of quoting. Quotes can't be part of the data unless you intend to `eval`. It's something to avoid unless no other solutions can be used. Read the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 2):

Don't put quotes (or escapes) in your data (i.e. parameters, variables, etc). Quotes go *around* data, not *in* data. If you want to pass multiple parameters to add to a `find` command, pass each one as a separate parameter (just as you would to `find` itself), and use `"$@"` to expand them (double-quotes required to avoid parsing weirdness).

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.[ch]" "$@"
```

Then run it as `test.sh -not -path "*examples*"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but my test.sh actually has its own command line options, so not all options for the ```find``` inside. I guess, if I use "$@", it would bring all command line options down to the ```find```, right?

Comment: @neuronmac Yes, unless you have some way to distinguish the flags for your command vs. those for `find`. But if there is a way to distinguish them (maybe put yours first, with a `--` to separate them from the `find` options?), that'd honestly be cleaner than trying to parse a command string in a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for static strings and double quotes for variables.

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -not -path "$1"
```

Note: Escape `*`, to stop the shell from expanding it. Run your script this way:

```
./myscript '*examples*'
```

Or this way:

```
./myscript \*examples\*
```